# Have each subclass contain a list of its own?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, subclass, class-variables

I wish to have a base class, that would make each subclass to contain a list without needing to do it manually for each subclass?
For example, when I create a `Subclass` from my `BaseClass`, I want my `Subclass` to have `element_list` list automatically.
Currently I do it like so:

```
class BaseClass:
    element_list = ['Base Element', 'More Element\'s']
    def do_stuff(): pass

class Subclass(BaseClass):
    # Replaces BaseClass' element_list
    element_list = ['Sub Element', 'More Sub Element\'s']
    def do_sub_stuff(): pass
```

Now as it stands, this seems easy to do manually, but I'd like this class system to be as user-friendly as possible for people who don't know that much of it (basically only read a tutorial hot to make these subclasses), and most classes are gonna have an empty element_list, or have the elements added later in the code after defining the class.

I'd love to have it so that there's an empty list by default, even if one is not manually defined in the subclass, and that each subclass would automatically have its own unique list.

Is this possible?

Comment: how about returning the list from a method, and in the overriding class, merge the two lists so you have all the elements?

Comment: If you want there to be an empty list by default, couldn't you set `element_list` to the empty list in `BaseClass`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this list? There is probably a better solution than lists, if we know more about the problem.

Comment: @sweeneyrod Then it wouldn't be unique, changing one of the lists in one of the subclasses would change each and every last one of the lists in the other subclasses. They'd all share the same list.

Comment: @Daniel I wish to have a list of classes, and when an instance of the subclass is intialized, I'd do `self.elements = [element_cls() for element_cls in self.element_list]`. Only requirement is that the subclasses of my baseclass need to look as simple as possible.

Comment: @MightyPork Yeah I figured that one out, but it's just not as elegant and simple looking as I'd like it to be. It'll have to do if there's no easier way, but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost never a good idea to have mutable object as class attributes. Just use tuples, you can always overwrite the attribute if you need to modify your list.

Comment: Will do, didn't event think of this possibility, even though it's quite obvious. Thanks a lot :)